# Forwarding/Redirecting email using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net job website. each company can post a vacancy and email address to contact to. I have found that competitors are copying the vacancies and email address from my site. How can I get rid of this ? What if i show a dummy email address on vacancy but when user copies this email address and sends email, it goes to actual vacancy email ? Is this possible using asp.net ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your purpose is only to hide the mail id, why show it in the first place?

You could easily provide  a mail link/button, and send an email using .net mail functions.

The mail address is available in code behind, but you don't write it to the page. If its not in the response, they can't copy it.

Answer (score 0):

If the information is on your website, I don't think you can stop other people from copying the links.

You could add a button to a form where the user can add details to a set of fields which you then send on to the advertising company. This is how lots of job websites work.